# ls for decreasing order in combination with another command

Tags: command-line

I know there is the `ls -r` command for listing in a decreasing order. But is there any simple way to do it with a combination with another function by only using `ls` and not its arguments?

Comment: What do you mean by this? What other function are you talking about?

Comment: Are you trying to do this just for education/amusement purposes, or are you trying to solve a real problem (and, if so, what is it)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
ls | sort -r | column
```

This runs `ls` to list (with no options) and pipes it to the `sort` command. `sort -r` sorts in reverse order (`man sort` for more options).  The output of the `sort` will be one per line.  To change it to the style of `ls`, aligned in columns, the output of `sort` is piped to the `column` command.

Comment: The normal output of `ls` isn't all on one line, it puts it in columns that fit the width of the terminal.

Comment: @Barmar - So it is! I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `tac`:

```
ls | tac
```

According to the `tac` man page:

```
tac - concatenate and print files in reverse
```